# How to use compute method in nested Hashmap

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

I have a nested map `Map<someKey, Map<String, Long> > days`.
I want to use Hashmap's compute method to modify this piece of code
I have a field which is of Long dataType called `numberOfDays`

```
Map<String, Long> match2 = new HashMap<>();
if (days.containsKey(matchingKey)) {
         match2 = days.get(matchingKey);
         if (match2.containsKey(mappingNumber)) {
            Long count = match2.get(mappingNumber);
            match2.put(mappingNumber, count + numberOfDays);
         } else {
            match2.put(mappingNumber, numberOfDays);
         }
      } else {
         match2.put(mappingNumber, numberOfDays);
      }
      days.put(matchingKey, match2);
```

I have written something like this

```
days.compute(matchingKey, (SomeKey, ValueMap) -> {
         ValueMap.compute(mappingNumber, (key, value) ->
            (value == null)? numberOfDays : value + numberOfDays
         );
         return VMValueMap;
      });
```

Now I am stuck here if it is possible to use compute method or not.
Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

The top level just needs to make use of `computeIfAbsent` to generate the outer `HashMap` if key is missing, and with that value use `compute` on the lower level to produce the modified count.

```
days.computeIfAbsent(matchingKey, k -> new HashMap<>())
    .compute(mappingNumber, 
             (key, value) -> (value == null) ? numberOfDays : value + numberOfDays);
```

You are using auto-boxed type `Long`. The add computation is easier to declare if you switch to `AtomicLong` and use `computeIfAbsent` to keep track of the counters, and add the values at the end. You can assign any value to local variables if you need the intermediate results or the new counter value:

```
Map<SomeKey, Map<String, AtomicLong>> days 
...
int newV = days.computeIfAbsent(matchingKey,   k -> new HashMap<>())
               .computeIfAbsent(mappingNumber, k -> new AtomicLong())
               .addAndGet(numberOfDays);
```

Comment: Instead of `.compute(mappingNumber,  (key, value) -> (value == null) ? numberOfDays : value + numberOfDays)` you can use `.merge(mappingNumber, numberOfDays, Long::sum)`